# How can i create Kafka topic running in different cluster from another spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have two clusters running Kafka and spark separately. I want to create a kafka-topic from spark cluster. I have noticed to create a topic we need to invoke Kafka-topics.sh which wont be available in spark cluster. command should invoked through shell.

eg: /kafka_topics.sh --zookeeper :2181 --create --topic test_topic

This script should be called from spark cluster and it should get executed on Kafka cluster.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have java api and maven dependencies(kafka and zookeeper) to create kafka topic as below. You can invoke the code from the code where you are submitting spark application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
    <artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
    <version>0.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.1</version>
</dependency>

import java.util.Properties;
import org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient;
import org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkInterruptedException;
import kafka.utils.ZKStringSerializer$;
import kafka.admin.AdminUtils;

public final class KafkaUtils {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
        KafkaUtils.createTopic("x.x.x.x:2181,y.y.y.y:2181", "topicName", 1, 0, new Properties());       
    }

    public static void createTopic(String zkHosts, String topicName, int numberOfPartition, int replicationFactor, Properties properties) {
        ZkClient zkClient = null;
        try {
            zkClient = getZkClient(zkHosts);
            AdminUtils.createTopic(zkClient, topicName, numberOfPartition, replicationFactor, properties);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (zkClient != null) {
                try {
                    zkClient.close();
                } catch (ZkInterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private static ZkClient getZkClient(String zkHosts) {
        ZkClient zkClient = null;
        // Zookeeper sessionTimeoutMs
        final int sessionTimeoutMs = 10000;
        // Zookeeper connectionTimeoutMs
        final int connectionTimeoutMs = 10000;
        zkClient = new ZkClient(zkHosts, sessionTimeoutMs, connectionTimeoutMs, ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
        return zkClient;
    }
}
```

Here x.x.x.x and y.y.y.y are zk cluster hosts for kafka. Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps a lot. Thanks. But im is there any way i can invoke using shell scripts? like <Kafka-cluster>/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper --topic <topic name> From spark cluster..I m not sure about SSH since both are in different cluster..

Comment: If there is n/w connectivity between spark and kafka and its zookeeper(2181 port open) clusters nodes, then another simple solution can be is download the kafka binary from http://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html and extract on one of the node of spark cluster and go to KAFKA_HOME and use the below command, which can be part of your shell script.

Comment: bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper x.x.x.x:2181,y.y.y.y:2181 --create --topic topicName --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1

Comment: Thanks Anupam..Is there any option other than download the kafka binary  in spark cluster?